# Magento - Need to launch model from html button press

Tags: php, magento

I've got a simple html button in tha admin area (custom module) i need to "launch" a model function and to pass to it a variable.

Which is the best way?

Dispatch an event and observe for it? any other simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to create you own controller and action.
When you click the button, send the request to that controller and action with a parameter (POST or GET) and in the action just add this:

```
$param = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('some_param');//get the parameter from GET
//or
//$param = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('some_param');//get the parameter from POST
Mage::getModel('some/model')->doSomeAction($param);
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

Comment: Thank you Marius....     i haven't think to the easiest way... post data directly to the controller.

Thanks also for the code tip! Let's try it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the point of your question but :

- Add your button and point it to a new controler's action
- Create a new action in your controller (in your model's module) or update/rewrite an existing one.
- load your model
- execute the function on it

No need to use a dispatchEvent here, unless you want to let other developers inject some code in yours.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the button you can form post (get or use ajax) the action to a controller, then from your controller you can call your model function.